# How to escape a string in system.data.sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, .net-4.5

I am executing an SQL query (system.data.SQLite) like so:

```
var color = "red";
var command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT something FROM tabletop WHERE color = '" + color + "'", Connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The color variable is a text supplied by the user.
How can I escape this text to prevent SQL injection?
Or is this bad practice and I should execute the query in some entirely different "protected" way?

Comment: You have to use the syntax shown in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015572/sqlite-exception-using-string-format-args-wrong-syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use parameterized queries:

```
var command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT something FROM tabletop WHERE color = @Color", Connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Color", color);
```

You can also pass an array of `SQLiteParameter`s into the `command.Parameters` collection like so:

```
SQLiteParameter[] parameters = { new SQLiteParameter("Color", color), new SQLiteParameter("Size", size) }; // etc.
command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Comment: Do I need to have `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` line for each variable, or is there some way to pass an array, or some different collection there?

Answer (score 2):

You do it with prepared statements:

```
SQLiteCommand sql = SQLiteDB.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO aziende VALUES (@id_azienda, @nome)";

SQLiteParameter lookupValue = new SQLiteParameter("@id_azienda");
SQLiteParameter lookupValue2 = new SQLiteParameter("@nome");

sql.Parameters.Add(lookupValue);
sql.Parameters.Add(lookupValue2);

lookupValue.Value = "Your unsafe user input goes here";
lookupValue2.Value = "Your second unsafe user input goes here";

sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```